# Get max items in array of lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have array of lists (string typed):

```
List<string>[] nodesAtLevel = new List<string>[20];
```

e.g:

```
[0] - List: "Hi", "There"
[1] - List: "Hi", "There", "Someone"
[2] - List: "Hi"
```

I need to write a LINQ operation that would return the array index of the biggest list.

Regard the example above, the LINQ operation should return 1 (because it has 3 items).

I know I should use "Where" and "Max" functions but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this query. First, you want to create a collection of objects that holds information about index of a list in the array and count of its items. Then, order this new collection by `Count`, select the first or last (depending on how you ordered the collection) and take an index.

```
var result = nodesAtLevel.Select((l, i) => new { Count = l.Count, Index = i })
                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                         .First()
                         .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Answer (score 1):

my version:

```
var max = nodesAtLevel.Select((l, i) => new { index = i, list = l })
                      .OrderBy(x => x.list.Count)
                      .Last().index;
```